# Returning results from many functions / statements

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin

I have a function that I will be running 10-50 times at once:

```
importsitechanges(33, 209703, 'Store Name', 'Addr', 'city', 'state', 'zip', 'phone')
```

This function that I made returns the number of changes made as a string.

When I run many of them at once in pgadmin, I only get the return string from the last one:

```
SELECT * FROM importsitechanges(33, 321344, 'Store Name', 'Addr', 'city', 'state', 'zip', 'phone');
SELECT * FROM importsitechanges(32, 209703, 'Store Name', 'Addr', 'city', 'state', 'zip', 'phone');
...
```

How can I get the return strings from all of these functions?

Comment: You can try to `UNION ALL` the single calls.  This way you'll get a table, one row for each execution.

Comment: That works perfectly! Thanks so much! For reference, I now run it as `SELECT * FROM importsitechanges(33, 321344, 'Store Name', 'Addr', 'city', 'state', 'zip', 'phone') UNION ALL 
SELECT * FROM importsitechanges(32, 209703, 'Store Name', 'Addr', 'city', 'state', 'zip', 'phone') UNION ALL ...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, as you already noticed, pgAdminIII shows only the latest result set.  A logical solution could be transforming your 10-50 result sets into one.   This can be achieved using `UNION ALL`:

```
SELECT * FROM importsitechanges(33, ...)
    UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM importsitechanges(22, ...)
    UNION ALL
...
```